# WCF JSON service never getting hit

Tags: c#, json, wcf-data-services

I am trying to get a WCF JSON service to work that uses HTTPS and I can not get it to work for the life of me. I keep getting 400 error I believe it has something to do with my web.config file. Here is what I have currently.

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity" closeTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="IBVProtoType.PostBack">
        <endpoint address="https://Securesite.com/Webservice.svc"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
          contract="IBVProtoType.PostBack"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

**Iservice**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "PostBack")]
    void PostBack(string data);
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bcadd339-662d-4751-b96a-ac09fd297d00/wcf-returning-415unsupported-media-type?forum=wcf

Comment: If I could down vote that I would as that page is mostly filled with 404 links. and tells me nothing.

Comment: Anyone else want to try?